# What do you mean by minimum height of a Binary Search Tree?

Tags: binary-trees, java

I came across the term "minimum height of a Binary Search Tree" (in Java) in class, but I don't fully understand. Could someone please elaborate on:
     (a) What it is ?
     (b) How to determine/find it ?

Comment: Can you give more context?

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/6277/30102

Comment: A possible meaning might be in the context of answering "What is the least possible height of a BST containing $n$ data values?", where the answer is "approximately $\log n$".

Answer (score -2):

Binary Search Trees(BST)are a class of data structures which are used to implement dynamic sets. They kind of store data pieces, whic are known as keys, and they also allow fast insertion and deletion of these keys. Also, they checkwhether a key is present in a tree.

I did not get your (b) part. Are you asking to determine whether a tree is BST or not?

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. You don't state what the term "minimum height of a binary search tree" means.